# Int + Str type python

Tags: python, string, int

So I have this code

```
la = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(la, "/builds", "w") as python_script_file:
    python_script_file.write(other_python_script)
```

My path contains letters and numbers:

`storage/0/downloads...`

And what should I do? It says I need int when I make int it says str.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 52, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

[Program finished]
```

So it's a loop, I can't do anything
I tried to search something, but it seems to be no one asked this before

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Edited, added traceback

Comment: Use `open` properly?

Comment: The error seems to be somewhere in your `Pydroid` IDE. You should check that you can correctly run a new python file with just `print("Hello World")` in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [documentation of open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). you need the file name as the **first** argument (not first and second).

Use `os.path.join` to join path segments to one:

```py
la = os.path.dirname(__file__)
fName = os.path.join(la,"builds")
with open(fName, "w") as python_script_file:
    python_script_file.write(other_python_script)
```